# Centralizar o menu ou por 10% de margem da esquerda sem comprometer a resposividade

Tags: html5, css3

```css
.nav-tabs {
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
.nav-tabs a {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li role="presentation" class="active" ><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="produto.html">Produtos</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="contato.html">Contato</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: bom a princípio se precisa editar e colocar o restante do css e do html...

Comment: Você pode usar `@media queries` para definir uma css específica apenas para determinados dispositivos, ou determinada resolução. [Saiba Mais](https://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/)

Comment: Você definiu o width do elemento?

Answer (score 0):

A explicação e mais exemplos estão [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp) , (em inglês)

Para centralizar um elemento use: `margin: auto;`

O trecho que mostrou ficaria assim:

```css
.nav-tabs {
    background-color: #ffff00; 
    margin: auto;
}
.nav-tabs a {
    color: red; 
}
```

Comment: Tentei, porém sem sucesso. O home fica na esquerda sem nehuma margem e quando coloco margin-left: 10%; todos os itens do menu ficam com margem.

Comment: A resposta mostra apenas a regra css que centraliza um elemento. (margin:auto;)
Como só apresentou uma linha de CSS, presumi que seria esta a que quer centralizar.
Edite sua questão, mostrando mais código, de forma que se possa entender qual a combinação html/css deve receber a regra.
Neste trecho que você publicou, não ha sequer relação entre o HTML e CSS.